# Command-W not working correctly on Safari

Tags: keyboard, safari

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> always worked in my Safari like this:

1. it closes all tabs
2. if there's no tab, it closes the window.

Now, #2 is not working anymore.

Any clues?

Comment: Did you try without any extensions enabled?

Comment: yes, no change at all.

Comment: So you have one Safari window open, with one tab, press Cmd-W and nothing happens?

Comment: yes. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `System Preferences…` application, and select the `Keyboard` pane.

Hit the `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab on top, and `Application Shortcuts` on the left. Is there an entry for `Close Tab ⌘W` or an entry for `Close Window` that's set to something else? If so, remove it with the +- widgets at the bottom of the window.

Without knowing what other applications you're running, that's the first place I can think of to check what might be intercepting it.

Comment: When I first detected this problem the behavior of safari was this: CMD W did not close any tab or window. THen I went to this window and added an entry for Close Tab as CMD W. Now If I have a safari window with multiple tabs, CMD close the tabs. When all tabs are closed and I am with just one safari window without tabs, CMD W does nothing. In the past, CMD W would close all tabs than the window where there was not more tabs to close.

Comment: AHA! That phrase of yours "applications intercepting it", lighted a bulb in my brain! That's it. I have installed an upgrade of Better Touch Tool that was using CMD W and crapping Safari!!! /&%#/&%#$!!!!  Thanks